# How to edit values in MySQL Workbench directly?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am using MySQL Workbench to manage a database, and I am unable to edit values in the database directly. When I click on a cell/value and choose "Open Value in Editor" and I change the text and click apply, the change doesn't persist. Would anyone know of the reason/solution to this?

Comment: You need to Synchronise your Database after changing your .mwb file.

Answer (score 5):

Once you are finished with editing the individual values in the result grid, you have to apply your changes to the DB:

[image]

Comment: You can also use the apply to generate an sql script that you can modify and then run in the same window multiple times or as a batch script. Only do this if you are familiar with the syntax. Think of the Apply button as a "safety" save button.

Comment: This is a review feature you can switch on and off via the preferences. And beside that it's also a useful feature for beginners to learn how an update query must be written.